# search min value in already summarized group in excel pivot

Tags: excel, pivot

Example:

```
Region - Customer - Value
1 - a - 2
1 - a - 3
1 - b - 4
2 - d - 1
2 - d - 5
2 - c - 6
2 - c - 1
```

I want to show min value in certain region by summarized customer. Somehow excel should first summarize values by customer  (a=5, B=4, C=7, d=6) and only than search min value by region.

Correct pivot table at the end would be:

```
Region - min value
1 - 4
2 - 6
```

Comment: Use a helper column with SUMIFS() to sum by the Customer and Region.  Then use a pivot table with that new column as the value and find the min by Region.

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact pivot table described (with only Region and Min Value columns), you need to add a helper column with the following formula (created after turning your data into a table to use table references):

`=SUMIFS([Value],[Region],[@Region],[Customer],[@Customer])`

Then add Region as Row Field, helper column as Data Field, then summarise values by Minimum.

Alternatively, you could generate a pivot table with the required values without a helper column, however you'll also need to also display the Customer column and apply a filter to it:

1. Create Pivot Table
2. Add Region as Row Field
3. Add Customer as Row Field
4. Add Value as Data Field
5. Change Report Layout to Tabular Form (PivotTable Tools > Design tab)
6. Remove Subtotals and Grand Totals (also on Design tab)
7. Right click on Customer Field in PivotTable
8. Select Filter > Top 10...
9. Set to: Show Bottom 1 Items by Sum of Value

[image: Top10]
[image: Pivot]